# :hover:before does not work with a link

Tags: html, css, hover

I am using [the code from CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/) to create a star rating. Additionally, I would like the user to be able to click on a star and go to a link. This is not working though.

My HTML:

```
<div class="rating">
    <span><a href="index.php?var=1">☆</a></span>
    <span><a href="index.php?var=2">☆</a></span>
    <span><a href="index.php?var=3">☆</a></span>
    <span><a href="index.php?var=4">☆</a></span>
</div>
```

And this is in the stylesheet:

```
.rating > span:hover:before {
    content: "\2605";
    position: absolute;
}

.rating {
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    direction: rtl;
}

.rating > span:hover:before, .rating > span:hover ~ span:before {
    content: "\2605";
    position: absolute;
}
```

Problem is that when I try clicking on the link, nothing happens.. Not even the cursor changes to a pointer. I'm guessing that's because a  gets put on top of the link when i hover it..? Is this correct? And how can I solve this problem?

Comment: did you tested .rating > span:hover::before?

Comment: @MajidAbbasi Yes, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put `span` inside `a` elements instead of `a` inside `span` :

```
<div class="rating">
    <a href="index.php?var=1"><span>☆</span></a>
    <a href="index.php?var=2"><span>☆</span></a>
    <a href="index.php?var=3"><span>☆</span></a>
    <a href="index.php?var=4"><span>☆</span></a>
</div>
```

Also, update your CSS selectors like this :

```
.rating > a:hover:before {
    content: "\2605";
    position: absolute;
}

.rating {
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    direction: rtl;
}

.rating > a:hover:before, .rating > a:hover ~ a:before {
    content: "\2605";
    position: absolute;
}
```

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/183gaqd9/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the spans and just use the a tag.  Then replace the span tags in your CSS with a tags and it should work as expected.  Here's what I did and it works as I think you'd expect.

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
  .rating > a:hover:before {
    content: "\2605";
    position: absolute;
}

.rating {
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    direction: ltr;
}

.rating > a:hover:before, .rating > a:hover ~ a:before {
    content: "\2605";
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="rating">
    <a href="index.php?var=1">☆</a>
    <a href="index.php?var=2">☆</a>
    <a href="index.php?var=3">☆</a>
    <a href="index.php?var=4">☆</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I answered right when you did, and I removed the <a> and did JS on the span, but after looking at your answer I feel it's the better of the two choices. With my answer, you get that one weirdo that disabled JS and it wouldn't work.

Comment: Lol.  There are plenty of tinfoil hats out there.  I considered JS as well, but it seemed like @jwnkim wanted something more HTML based so went this direction.

Comment: That's right, i'm trying to work without JS. But thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok to use Javascript?  I was able to make it work fine using the following:

```
<div class="rating">
  <span onclick="alert('4');">☆</span>
  <span onclick="alert('3');">☆</span>
  <span onclick="alert('2');">☆</span>
  <span onclick="alert('1');">☆</span>
</div>
```

Instead of alert, you can create a function that takes the value 1-4, and changes the location from that supplied value.

https://jsfiddle.net/kevinbburns/oxgr32yn/2/